# Is it possible to register all tables for Database Change Notification in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I was looking for something to catch all Database changes happening in Oracle Database. So I got this documentation from Oracle. It is Database Change Notification ( https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28815 ) and I got it working for a single table as described the example in the document. I would like to listen changes for all the tables in a Database. Is it possible with this method? Can someone help me. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible is possible, you only need to register all tables as you did with the first one. However it is not very recommendable. Database Change Notification works good with tables that rarely change. The data cache has to be updated or invalidated when the data changes in the database.

Therefore, good practice is to identify the tables you want to enable for DCN. Not all tables are suitable. Understand your data model and apply it to those which rarely change.

Oracle suggest this functionality might be of use in multi-tier applications, where semi-static data is cached in the middle tier. In such a setup, modification of the base data could trigger the middle tier to refresh its cached data.